# Error in increasing Datetime in Oracle/PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

Here I'm using a loop from  StartDateTime to  EndDatetime and adding 1 hour in every iteration. Everything is working in Loop.But problem is in insert query.Please Check the insert query.

```
declare
StartDateTime   TIMESTAMP :=to_date( '2017-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd       
hh24:mi:ss');
EndDateTime   TIMESTAMP :=to_date( '2017-12-31 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd 
hh24:mi:ss');
dateti TIMESTAMP;
dateti2 TIMESTAMP;
StartDateTime1 TIMESTAMP;
sub INTEGER;
semester Number;
begin

sub:=( CAST( EndDateTime AS DATE ) - CAST( StartDateTime AS DATE ) )  ;

FOR i IN  0 .. 1
LOOP
StartDateTime1:=StartDateTime+i;
for idx in 0..2 loop
dateti:=to_date(StartDateTime1+(idx/24.0),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
dateti2:=to_date(StartDateTime1+((idx+1)/24.0)+ interval '-1' second,'yyyy-
mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');

      case 
        when to_number(to_char(dateti ,'Q'))>6 then semester:=to_number(2);
       else semester:=to_number(1);
        end case;
```

Problem start from here in insert query.It saying non numeric character found.DateSlotStart and DateSlotEnd datatype is Timestramp .Please see the image and advise what should I change?

[image]

```
  insert into DimDate1(DateSlotStart,DateSlotEnd,
  "Date",SlotName,MonthName,MonthNumberOfYear,Quarter,Year,Semester) values 
   (to_date(dateti ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') ,to_date(dateti2 ,'yyyy-mm-dd 
    hh24:mi:ss') ,
   to_date(dateti ,'yyyy-mm-dd'),to_char(dateti ,'hh24:mi' )||' To 
   '||to_char(dateti2 ,'hh24:mi' ),to_char(dateti 
    ,'Month'),to_number(to_char(dateti ,'mm')),to_number(to_char(dateti ,'Q')),
  to_number(to_char(dateti ,'YYYY')) , semester);

end loop;


   END LOOP;
  end;
/
```

Please also check the this
[image]

Comment: Provide the DDL you used to create table `DimDate1`

Comment: I've added DDL  @KaushikNayak

Comment: By DDL  i meant the `create table DimDate1  statement` . Run this query and let me know the output. `select
   dbms_metadata.GET_DDL('TABLE','DIMDATE1') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: [Err] ORA-31603: object "DIMDATE1" of type TABLE not found in schema "MY_ERP_LOCAL_DB"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 1546
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 1583
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 1901
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 2792
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 4333
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: not found in schema "MY_ERP_LOCAL_DB".What can I do now?

Comment: is it created in a different schema?

Comment: as per my knowledge it is not.Is there any way to check it?

Comment: OK. just do describe table and paste the output. That would be sufficient. Paste the script output.not image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158264/discussion-between-kaushik-nayak-and-navid-anjum).

Comment: CREATE TABLE "WH_ZOO"."DIMDATE1" (
"DATESLOTKEY" NUMBER(10) NOT NULL ,
"DATESLOTSTART" TIMESTAMP(3)  NOT NULL ,
"DATESLOTEND" TIMESTAMP(3)  NOT NULL ,
"Date" DATE NOT NULL ,
"SLOTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
"MONTHNAME" NVARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ,
"MONTHNUMBEROFYEAR" NUMBER(3) NOT NULL ,
"QUARTER" NUMBER(3) NOT NULL ,
"YEAR" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL ,
"SEMESTER" NUMBER(3) NOT NULL 
)

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "WH_ZOO"."DIMDATE_SEQ_TR1" BEFORE INSERT ON "WH_ZOO"."DIMDATE1" REFERENCING OLD AS "OLD" NEW AS "NEW" FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.DateSlotKey IS NULL)
BEGIN
 SELECT DimDate_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.DateSlotKey FROM DUAL;
END;;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to convert `TIMESTAMP` to date where it is not required. And it is always better to use `CAST` when you need to convert it to `DATE`. Replace your insert with this. It should work.

```
   INSERT INTO dimdate1 (
        dateslotstart,
        dateslotend,
        "Date",
        slotname,
        monthname,
        monthnumberofyear,
        quarter,
        year,
        semester
    ) VALUES (
        dateti,
        dateti2,
        CAST (dateti AS DATE),
        TO_CHAR(dateti,'hh24:mi')
        || ' To '
        || TO_CHAR(dateti2,'hh24:mi'),
        TO_CHAR(dateti,'Month'),
        to_number(TO_CHAR(dateti,'mm') ),
        to_number(TO_CHAR(dateti,'Q') ),
        to_number(TO_CHAR(dateti,'YYYY') ),
        semester
    );
```

Comment: I'm getting error in "[Err] ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes".

Comment: It is not related to insert or conversion. You have to check whether you are running into an infinite loop with your PL/SQL code.

Comment: Ok.I'm checking